# Rehydrating Directory from Azure Archive storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to rehydrate all the contents inside a directory present in Azure archive storage but I am not able to as the option of change access tier is only available for files not for the directories in any GUI 
and there is no Commandlet as well.

Comment: You can try Cerebrata Cerulean (https://www.cerebrata.com). It allows you to change the access tier for all blobs in a directory. Disclosure - I am part of the team which has built this tool. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri Is this tool free for enterprise use as well and does it provide the level of security?

Comment: Please reach out to me through our support channel with your questions and I’ll try to answer them. I don’t think this is the right place to discuss this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no concept of folders in blob storage ;) they are only virtual parts of a blobs path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @silent mentioned, as a matter of fact, folders in blob storage is not real folder  concept that we know. It is called "virtual folders" that providing a way to manage blobs by using forward slashes in the name as a delimiter.

There is no actions on virtual folder.If you want to rehydrate all the blobs from a virtual folder, try the PowerShell command below :

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$acc = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name "<your storage account name>" -ResourceGroupName "<your storage account resource group>"

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Prefix "<your folder/directory name>" -Container "<your container name>" -Context $acc.Context | Where-Object{$_.ICloudBlob.Properties.StandardBlobTier -eq "Archive"} #get all of your archived blobs under a virtual folder,including blobs in sub virtual folders 

foreach($blob in $blobs){
    $blob.ICloudBlob.SetStandardBlobTier("Hot");
}
```

Once your run this command, your blobs will pending to hot tier , you can check your blobs on Azure portal:
[image]

As [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-rehydration#rehydrate-an-archived-blob-to-an-online-tier) indicated , it will take several hours to complete.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Hello, is there anything else I can assist ?

Comment: Hey Stanley, Thanks for your Answer the only thing I was missing while creating this script was -Prefix part